# Showing 1/g is a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g:(X, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be a measurable function. Then could anyone give me a simple proof on how to show $1/g$, $g \neq 0$ is a measurable function?

Comment: Is it? $0$ is a perfectly good measurable function...

Comment: I thought $1/0$ isn't defined

Comment: Exactly. So if $g \equiv 0$, $1/g$ is not measurable.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I forgot to mention the assumption $g \neq 0$, edited the question now

Answer (score 0):

$ x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} $ is a continuous function on $\overline{\mathbb{R}} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, and the composition of a continuous function with a measurable one is measurable.